# Laravel cURL error 28: SSL connection timeout

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl

I have a form with google recaptcha (if it does anything to do with this error) in my website. I'm running this project locally and sometimes get this error:

> ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186:
>       cURL error 28: SSL connection timeout (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

When I refresh the form this error disappears. I checked some solution on stackoverflow and added `set_time_limit(0);` in my form handling controller but it didn't work